# Future inside a stream, how to populate user onAuthStateChanged

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, future

I'm trying to load additional data from Firebase associated with the User document during `onAuthStateChanged` but as always when working with Streams or Futures, I get some kind of error like this one:
`The return type 'Future<dynamic>' isn't a 'User', as required by the closure's context.`

```
  Future _populateCurrentUser(FirebaseUser user) async {
    print("populating user $user");
    if (user != null) {
      _currentUser = await _api.getUser(user.uid);
      return _currentUser;
    }
  }

  @override
  Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map((FirebaseUser user) {
      return _populateCurrentUser(user); // tried await here but just more error hell
    });
  }
```

I tried using `await` and `async`, even `async*` and `yield` (`yield*`?  `yield@#$`?) on different lines but after like dozens and dozens and dozens of tutorials on this stuff I'm ready to throw away my dev career and take up gardening before my mind snaps completely.  Please help.

Comment: have you tried .then()?

Comment: It seems that the error is because you returned the value of populateCurrentUser, which is a Future, inside of the getter which returns stream. As far as I can understand, removing that return should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I just needed `asyncMap`, which "acts like `map`" but if the mapping function contains a Future it'll wait for it to complete:

```
Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged => _auth.onAuthStateChanged.asyncMap(_populateCurrentUser);
```